# Apache Calcite - How to Integrate CSV and MySQL

Tags: apache-calcite

It is easy to use each adapter by command connect.

for example:
!connect jdbc:calcite:model=target/test-classes/model.json admin admin

but I have not found in documentation how to do queries involving heterogeneous sources.

I would like to do a query involving entities that are in the two sources, CSV and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two schemas in your in `model.json` file, one that targets CSV source and another one that targets JDBC MySQL source.

If the sources contain tables that are somehow connected, then you can create queries like this:

```
SELECT csv_source.table1.field1, mysql_source.table2.field2,
       csv_source.table1.joint_field, mysql_source.table2.joint_field
FROM csv_source.table1 
     JOIN mysql_source.table2 
          ON joint_field;
```